# Mobile first? What do i need to do that?

Tags: html, css, mobile, desktop

I've started to really get into coding using HTML5 and CSS3 over the past 3 weeks and even started on my own project.

I've come across people saying "MOBILE FIRST!!" a lot along the way, and I've been looking into it and found out how to do it using media queries.

I use the Atom text editor to write my source code, and view my html file on chrome.

My question is, what program or extension do people normally use to view their code on different device types?

Many thanks!

Dan

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and note the part which says you shouldn't ask about "Product or service recommendations or comparisons"

Comment: Note that the dev tool phone simulator may not give exact result as an actual phone in some cases, always check your work on a phone

Comment: **Mobile First** is the process of designing webpages with default CSS for mobile devices. Then, when the device moves up to another screen size, you create a media query and make adjustments in that media query, with the default CSS being the fallback. It's an easy process once you get used to it. There are no extensions for this, but I'd recommend a few things... **1)** Learn CSS back to front **2)** Learn SCSS or SASS (or some CSS preprocessor) and lastly, **3)** Find an extension like Live Server that will let you dev on one screen, and see the result immediately on the other.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think there's a reason to use any extension. You can quickly get all possible dimensions by using the developer tools.

Open the developer tools using `Ctrl+Shift+C` on Windows or `Command+Option+J` on Mac and toggle the device toolbar `Ctrl+Shift+M` or `Command+Option+M` on a Mac.

Then, at the top of the screen, you have the option to choose the height and width you desire. You can also create custom device dimensions by clicking on the `edit` button inside the dimensions menu:
[image: dimensions menu]

In the menu that opens, you can add your custom device/use an existing device from the list:
[image: custom device menu]

What I usually do when I work on a responsive design is to resize the site's width manually. I also use my mobile device in order to see the differences more reliably. ([Gif of the resizing](https://i.gyazo.com/04cbe9de8b47e2abba255f6da38e0517.mp4))

As the user [Huangism](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1058134/huangism) mentioned, resizing through the dev-tools won't always give you reliable results, which is why you should check the design through an actual mobile device.

> Note that the dev tool phone simulator may not give exact result as an actual phone in some cases, always check your work on a phone

---

There's a chrome extension that I used to have, but I didn't find it too comfortable to use. You can take a look; it's called [Responsive Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/responsive-viewer/inmopeiepgfljkpkidclfgbgbmfcennb?hl=en)

You choose which devices/dimensions you want, and you get a layout of the selected devices:
[image: Responsive Viewer]

In general, I find manual resizing the best option when working on responsive designs.

Comment: I didn't get chance to thank you yesterday for this. It describes everything i was looking for. Thank you so much for your help! :)